# Realtek HD Audio changing default device automatically

Tags: audio

I used to have [Asus M4A89GTD PRO](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A89GTD_PRO/) motherboard which automatically offered me to set headphones as default device once I plugged 'em in and when I unplugged my headphones it automatically changed to my primary speakers but now as I had to get new motherboard([ASRock Z77 Pro4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Pro4/?cat=Specifications)) for my new processor that isn't happening anymore eventhough they both have Realteks integrated soundcard, I've installed the drivers and I have Realtek HD audio manager running fine and I am able to switch between devices manually but that's so slow and annoying for such a simple task.

I usually also have to do that quickly when I am getting a Skype call for example and I have always let the caller to wait because of this. I thought my integrated sound card might not support jack plug detaction but then again, cmon' its 2012 already!

Is there some setting that I could change to make it offer those things by default or is there anything to do? I don't think a dedicated soundcard would be good for me as I am not much of a music maker..

I am using latest driver from ASRock's site with Windows 8 pro

Comment: If the hardware (specific motherboard model) does not support jack detection, how do you suppose you can "make it offer those things by default"?

Comment: How do I know if the hardware supports it?

Comment: Download and read the manual.